# this.context empty on componentDidMount but only when testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use reacts context API. I have a LoginContext and can reach it in the render by using a `LoginContext.Consumer` tag.

However, I want to be able to reach this context in the `componentDidMount` function. I have specified the contextType in the class and can use `this.context` fine in the application.

However, when it comes to testing this doesn't seem to work. I mock the context and wrap the component in a provider. This works fine for the render method but not for anything in a lifecycle method. On debugging i can see `this.context` is empty.

Component:

```
import { LoginContext } from '../context';

 class Field extends Component {

static contextType = LoginContext;

componentDidMount() {
        this.context.registerInput(this.props.name, this.props.isRequired); //this is empty in tests
    }

 render() {
        const { type, isRequired, name, label, placeholder } = this.props;
        const { registered } = this.state;
        const labelClass = `form__label ${isRequired ? 'form__label--required' : ''}`;

        return (<LoginContext.Consumer>
            {({ registerInput }) => {

                //  this.handleRegisterInput(registerInput); *it exists fine here in tests?

                return (
                    <Fragment>
                       <h1>dummy implementation</h1>
                    </fragment>)
 }}

        </LoginContext.Consumer>
        );
}
}
```

context:

```
import {createContext} from 'react';

export const LoginContext = createContext({
    registerInput: () => {}
});
```

test:

```
test('it should register the input when the component mounts',() => {

        const labelName = 'Test';
        const context = {
            registerInput: jest.fn()
        };

        render(
            <LoginContext.Provider value={context}>
                <Field name={labelName} isRequired={true}/>
            </LoginContext.Provider>
        );
        expect(context.registerInput).toBeCalledWith(labelName,true);
    });
```

the result of the test is:   `Error: Uncaught [TypeError: registerInput is not a function]` but it works fine live?

Comment: What is `getInputValid`?

Comment: my bad copied the wrong error.